# restify's body parser is not working for some reason

Tags: node.js, webserver, middleware, restify, body-parser

I don't understand why this works:

```
instance.use(restify.bodyParser());
```

but this doesn't work:

```
instance.use((req, res, next) => {
  restify.bodyParser();
  next();
});
```

**UPD:** I've tried to `restify.bodyParser()(req, res, next)`. In fact it doesn't work for some reason.

`restify.bodyParser()` exports array of functions: [read, parseBody]. So using `restify.bodyParser()(...)` throws error `... is not a function`.

I'm still trying to achieve why so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use` expects an [argument of the form `function (req, res, next)` or an array of functions of this form](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/blob/5.x/lib/server.js#L628). `restify.bodyParser()` is an array of functions of this form. Hence, you will need pass `req`, `res`, `next` to each of the functions in the array. Depending on what you want to do, you might want to return an array of middlewares or call the middlewares in sequence.

Comment: Damn, it's that simple ) Thank you

Comment: I've just tested it. For some reason it is not working. See UPD in question

Comment: You're right, `use` can also accept an array of middlewares, didn't think about that. I updated my answer, I hope that helps. The exact usage highly depends on our use case, though, so I removed the code example.

Answer (score 0):

In case you come here looking for some answer to same error message 'restify.bodyParser is not a function'...

Since restify version 5.*, restify's bodyParser function shall be found as:

`restify.plugins.bodyParser()`

https://github.com/restify/node-restify/issues/1414

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Restify, use the plugin `restify.plugins.bodyParser()`.